# Why this simple SSIS Data Flow freeze?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

It is weird this simply data flow is freezing after several successful loads. 
Data flow consist of OLE DB source and OLE DB destination. Connections are good since I test it in connection manager. 
In the source, I can see expected data from preview option. However, no data load to destination table because of freeze. Source table has just several rows. And no any error is shown. It seems SSIS go to a unlimited loop.

What reason may result into freeze and how to debug it.

Comment: The possibilities of why are pretty wide open. My two favorite answers would be "something is blocking the query in the source" or "something is blocking the insert in the destination" It could be neither. It could be something like horrible network latency or a memory starved server in the mix.

Comment: I would install [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) on the source and target server and start up your package. Then execute the stored proc on those servers and get an idea of what is happening with your boxes and identify what is causing your blockage. The more astute readers would say, why not run a profiler trace or fire up Extended Events. You are 100% correct in that is the best way to handle it but not as comfortable of a starting point for neophytes as running a proc.

Answer (score 0):

Check if on the DB source you are also using the target table on the query. (e.g. select only the non existing rows)

If so, then create a tmp table, write on that and then load it to the final table.

Comment: This answer is only applicable in a very small subset of potential problems. Answering a question more than 8 years old it is not adding value, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I execute a transaction which wasn't committed. And so ,it was affecting in SSIS Data flow task.
So make sure you don't have any pending transaction to commit or rollback it.